# Large Bash Arrays or Log Out Termination

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, perl, shell

I am using bash script that calls a Perl script to perform a job. The results of that job are then appended to a array in bash and summed. The summation after each time the Perl script is call is printed. After the script runs for a while it stops printing the sum without an error message.

Example:

```
for i in {1..1999}; 
do
  fi="$(printf "%06d" $i)_sys6_uw_lipid_data.pdb"
  r_sq_value=$(perl r_value.pl "$fi")
  all_r_sq_values+=($r_sq_value)

sum=$(
awk 'BEGIN {t=0; for (i in ARGV) t+=ARGV[i]; print t}' "${all_r_sq_values[@]}"
)

echo "$sum <--- SUM"

done
```

The script works just fine for a while but after a long time the script stops printing the sum.

Example:

```
... skipping ... 
5.20884e+06 <--- SUM
5.22297e+06 <--- SUM
5.23754e+06 <--- SUM
5.25246e+06 <--- SUM
5.26714e+06 <--- SUM
5.28179e+06 <--- SUM
5.29737e+06 <--- SUM
 <--- SUM
 <--- SUM
 <--- SUM
 <--- SUM
 <--- SUM
```

Without an error I am not sure if this is because of the script or because the computer is terminating the job due to it going to sleep. All the data files that it reads are full and work individually with the Perl script.

Any suggestion or comments are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `fi` does not seems to be a good variable name (see if..fi)

Comment: I have correct the "fi" variable but the script is still having the same problem.

Comment: I suspect you have reached the limit on the length of awk's parameter list. It's easy enough to add together all the elements of an array without using awk, and I suggest you do that in shell code instead.

Comment: @Borodin Do you have an example I could try. Awk seems to be the most effective method.

Comment: Do you need the array? Why not just add each `r_sq_value` directly to `sum` instead of building an array first?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
for i in {1..1999}; 
 do
  fi="$(printf "%06d" $i)_sys6_uw_lipid_data.pdb"
  r_sq_value=$(perl r_value.pl "$fi")
  (( all_r_sq_values += ($r_sq_value) ))

sum=$(
 awk 'BEGIN {t=0; for (i in ARGV) t+=ARGV[i]; print t}'     "${all_r_sq_values[@]}"
)

echo "$sum <--- SUM"

done
```

Comment: It would help enormously if you highlighted what changes you had made and explained why you thought they would help

Comment: @Borodin , how do i highlight ?